# Loading resource failed on DoPostBack link click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to download an ZIP file available by clicking on aspx page link with CasperJS. However my programm fail and return "Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 200)".

My code :

```
 var casper = require('casper').create({
        pageSettings: {
            userName: 'myusername',
            password: 'mypwd',
            localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled: 'true',
            XSSAuditingEnabled: 'true',
            webSecurityEnabled: false
        }
    });

    casper.start('https://mysite/login.aspx');

    casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)');

    // some code for identification...

    casper.thenOpen('https://mysite/mypage.aspx');

    casper.waitForSelector(
            'a[id="myidlink"]',
            function() {
                this.click('#myidlink');
            },
            function() {
                this.log('TIMEOUT!','error');
                this.exit(62);
            },
            10000   
    );

    casper.waitForSelector('#myidlink');

    casper.on('resource.received', function (resource) {
        if (resource.contentType == "application/zip" && resource.stage == 'end'){
            this.log('resource.id : ' + resource.id, 'info');
            this.log('resource.url : ' + resource.url, 'info');
        }
    });

    casper.run();
```

I execute this code in ubuntu terminal with command :

```
casperjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=any --verbose --log-level=debug mycasperjs.js
```

Console log return "loading resource failed" :

> ```
> [info] [phantom] Starting...
> ...
> [debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: #myidlink
> [debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: #myidlink
> [debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: #myidlink
> [info] [phantom] Step anonymous 9/10: done in 8142ms.
> [debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://mysite/mypage.aspx
> [warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 200): https://mysite/mypage.aspx
> [info] [phantom] Step _step 10/10 mysite/mypage.aspx (HTTP 200)
> [info] [phantom] Step _step 10/10: done in 9890ms.
> [info] [phantom] resource.id : 49
> [info] [phantom] resource.url : mysite/mypage.aspx
> [info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 40ms.
> [info] [phantom] Done 10 steps in 9948ms
> ```

Versions used :

```
phantomjs --version
1.9.2
casperjs --version
1.1.0-beta3
```

Any help is welcome!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can start by upgrading to a newer PhantomJS version. Try v2.0.0 (needs CasperJS from git), v1.9.8 or v1.9.7.

Comment: Hello Artjom and thanks for your answer. I have tried with the last PhantomJS version (v2.0) but i have the same problem.

Comment: Don't use an IE user agent string, because the server could try to do network stuff that PhantomJS isn't capable of.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I deleted the user agent definition (the problem persist).